# SQL Adding a minus in a number if it is in another

Tags: sql, sas

I have a question for you, I don't know how to do it, I need to create a procedure if or case when. Relying on the back in the Salary column, some value has a minus, e.g. -316183.1021. This will add a minus to the value in the NOMINAL MAX column
For example here: ( This is result after sql in excel )

````
If SALARY = "-" then NOMINAL_MAX*(-1)```
````

[image]

Comment: Are they stored as varchar or number? Also please post your DB product?

Comment: What? So you want to check if salary is less than 0?

Comment: Its number(numeric) . I want to add a minus in nominal_max if there's a minus in salary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  update <table>
  set nominal_max = -nominal_max
  where nominal_max > 0 and salary < 0
```

Comment: Is there for SAS procedure ?

Comment: `Proc SQL;` is the procedure

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SIGN` function:

```
SELECT NOMINAL_MAX * SIGN(SALARY) AS NOMINAL_MAX_New
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot is there change to use a If statment ?

Comment: Yes you can use `IF` statement too: `SELECT IF(SALARY < 0, -NOMINAL_MAX, NOMINAL_MAX)`. Result will be same but `SIGN` function makes it simpler.